# Google App Engine JDO Relationships (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

Take a look at the first example of http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html (Owned One-to-One Relationships).

I dont quite understand one thing.
If i get a Employee from my PersistanceManager, will i get the ContactInfo at the same time, or will it get the ContactInfo when i try to use it?

If it does get it at the same time, how about Owned One-to-Many Relationsships?
Just to make an example,lets say Employee has a List containing 100 ContactInfos.
Does this mean i will get all the 100 ContactInfos when i get my Employee?

Thanks
//F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you will not get child data when you load the parent data.  However, if you try and access the child it will be loaded at that time.  This is called **lazy loading**.  An important note is that once you have closed the JDO transaction if you try and access a lazily loaded property you will get an exception (since the entity is now detached).

You can configure eager loading on an entity using JDO **fetch groups**.  Eager loading will load all the child data when you load the parent.  This is useful if you need to access the property after a transaction or if you need to send the entity across the network to a client.

Recommended reading:

[Fetch Groups](http://www.jpox.org/docs/1_1/fetchgroup.html)

[JDO Layer Design](http://www.jpox.org/docs/guides/jdo/daolayer_design.html)

Comment: Best not to refer to those pages since they are for JPOX which ceased to exist in 2008. Better to go via http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/ since that is what you're using

Comment: @DataNucleus: The link in your comment is broken too. I'm trying to get eager fetching of children working with DataNucleus/JDO/MySQL using a FetchGroup and `PersistenceManager.newQuery()`. Lazy loading works so I know I've got the relationship mapping correct. But when I try eager loading, I get no children. I'm just looking for docs with examples. If you could update the link, that would be great.

Comment: It wasn't when the comment was made, but sadly GAE is still stuck on ancient versions. Just use http://www.datanucleus.org   and navigate from there